# Counting segments without the function Count

Tags: arrays, algorithm, count, iteration, code-complexity

I had the next problem: Given an array, count the number of segments of length k in which this happens; the number of positives in the left-half of the segment is bigger or equal to the right-half.

As an example (imagine segments can only be even, so that there is no discussion about what a half is):

```
k=2 ---> count(array[-4,-2,2,1],k) ---> 2, as [-4,-2] fulfills and also [2,1]
k=4 ---> count(array[-4,-2,2,1],k) ---> 0, as [-4,-2,2,1] does not fulfil.
k=6 ---> count(array[-4,-2,2,1],k) ---> 0, as there are not length 6 segments.
```

I have solved it recursively, using the function Count, in a trivial way: I move the array from left to right, enumerating all the segments of length k, and applying the count on each of those. It is done in Dafny:

```
function method Count_segments(sequ: seq<int>, seg_length:int): int
{
  if |sequ| == 0 then 0
  else (if (Count(x => x >= 0, sequ[0..seg_length/2])) >= (Count(x => x >= 0, sequ[seg_length/2..seg_length])) then
        1 + if (|sequ|-1 < seg_length) then 0 //I add the condition that says that if in the next iteration, sequ will be smaller than the sequence_length, then we end.
            else Count_segments(sequ[1..], seg_length)
       else if (|sequ|-1 < seg_length) then 0
            else Count_segments(sequ[1..], seg_length)
       )
}
```

But, obviously, using Count, I am not doing a linear search iteratively (in the first example, instead of searching 4 times, it does 6 times). I would like to implement this in O(n) but cannot find any info, does anyone have an idea? I do not care about the programming language (can answer me in any language), but about the algorithm itself.

Thanks!!

Comment: ..and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I said: a simple algorithm using Count, I will post it in the original message :)

Comment: Can you also provide some `sample inputs`? It helps to better understand the problem.

Comment: Of course! Added.